# Insert grouped data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting expected results from my query, I am using group by to group the data on the basis of different Ids.

The problem I am facing is that I have to insert this grouped data in the table called gstl_calculated_daily_fee, but when I pass the grouped result to variables called @total_mada_local_switch_high_value and @mada_range_id and insert them in the table then I get only the last result of the query in the table.

**Sample result:**

```
Fee       range_id
1.23        1
1.22        2
2.33        3
```

**I get only 2.33 and 1 after I insert but I have to insert the whole result in to the table.**

Please suggest how can I insert the whole query result into the table.  Below is the query:

```
     DECLARE @total_mada_local_switch_high_value  decimal(32,4) = 0.00;
     DECLARE @mada_range_id int = 0;
select
    @total_mada_local_switch_high_value =  SUM(C.settlement_fees),
    @mada_range_id = C.range_id
From
(
    select
        *
        
    from
        (

            select
                rowNumber = @previous_mada_switch_fee_volume_based_count + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(MONTH, x_datetime) ORDER BY x_datetime)),
                tt.x_datetime
            from gstl_trans_temp tt where (message_type_mapping = 0220) and card_type ='GEIDP1' and response_code IN(00,10,11)  and tran_amount_req >= 5000
         
        ) A

        CROSS APPLY
            (
                select
                     rtt.settlement_fees,
                     rtt.range_id
                From gstl_mada_local_switch_fee_volume_based rtt
                    where A.rowNumber >= rtt.range_start
                        AND (A.rowNumber <= rtt.range_end OR rtt.range_end IS NULL)
            ) B 
) C

group by CAST(C.x_datetime AS DATE),C.range_id


    
        

    -- Insert Daily Volume      
    INSERT INTO 
            gstl_calculated_daily_fee(business_date,fee_type,fee_total,range_id) 
    VALUES 
            (@tlf_business_date,'MADA_SWITCH_FEE_LOCAL_CARD', @total_mada_local_switch_high_value, @mada_range_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no need for variables here. You can insert the aggregated results directly.

**Sample data**

```
create table Data
(
  Range int,
  Fee money
);  
insert into Data (Range, Fee) values
(1, 1.00),
(1, 0.50),
(2, 3.00),
(3, 0.25),
(3, 0.50);

create table DataSum
(
  Range int,
  FeeSum money
);
```

**Solution**

```
insert into DataSum (Range, FeeSum)
select d.Range, sum(d.Fee)
from Data d
group by d.Range;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4288a51ea998e740ab600acbb8d782b) to see things in action.